# View state in Visualforce components

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, dynamic-visualforce, viewstate

I am developing a VF page which will have two components. These two components will be placed multiple times on the same page with different input parameters. I am not sure how much view state will they consume. The question is not about view state of the page, the question is about the view state of the page when there are multiple visualforce components in the page.

Comment: it depends on what is in your component. it hard to tell from provided detail. you can check it enable the viewstate.

Comment: In one component there will be some output fields and in another there will be dynamically generated table. @TusharSharma. I wanted to confirm before I implementing.

Comment: viewstate depends on the number of components (exploded) and their associated controller data required to restore state. Use of `transient` modifier can help. Read `Visualforce in Practice` for a good discussion